# NotifyPropertyChanged of a Calculated property when Items in List Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I Have a model SupplierInvoice as follows:

```
public class SupplierInvoice
{
    public bool Use { get; set; }
    public ApInvoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

And a ViewModel with a list of this model:

```
private List<SupplierInvoice> _SupplierInvoices;
public List<SupplierInvoice> SupplierInvoices
{
    get
    {
        return this._SupplierInvoices;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._SupplierInvoices != value)
        {
            this._SupplierInvoices = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SupplierInvoices");
        }
    }
}
```

within this ViewModel I have a calculated property too:

```
public decimal ApTotal
{
    get
    {
        decimal total = 0;

        if (this.SupplierInvoices != null)
        {
            foreach (SupplierInvoice invoice in this.SupplierInvoices)
            {
                if (invoice.Use)
                {
                    total += invoice.Invoice.MthInvBal1;
                }
            }
        }

        return total;
    }
}
```

this calculated property returns the sum of the balance of all the invoices (if the invoice's Use property is true). The Use property is selected to be true on the view with a checkbox in a grid.

Now... the question is: How do I NotifyPropertyChanged of this calculated property (ApTotal) when the Use property of the SupplierInvoice model has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing your `List<TObject>` by an `ObservableCollection<TObject>` will do the trick.

From what I remember the `List` isn't propagating the PropertyChangedEvent to the UI thread.

Comment: I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the Model and used NotifyPropertyChanged on the Use property too however this doesn't resolve the issue. I need to notify the UI that ApTotal has changed since the Use property has been selected or deselected in the List

Comment: Are you using a two way binding in your xaml view ?

Comment: I am not using two way on ApTotal as it is a readonly and therefore twoway won't work. However on the Use property of SupplierInvoice the list is made up of I do use TwoWay

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit naughty, but you could always do this:

```
private List<SupplierInvoice> _SupplierInvoices;
public List<SupplierInvoice> SupplierInvoices
{
    get
    {
        return this._SupplierInvoices;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._SupplierInvoices != value)
        {
            this._SupplierInvoices = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SupplierInvoices");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ApTotal");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a calculated property, you just need to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event from the other properties that are involved in the calculation. So as your `ApTotal` property is calculated from just the `SupplierInvoices` property, then you can just notify the interface from that property setter:

```
public List<SupplierInvoice> SupplierInvoices
{
    get
    {
        return this._SupplierInvoices;
    }
    set
    {
        if (this._SupplierInvoices != value)
        {
            this._SupplierInvoices = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SupplierInvoices");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ApTotal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This however does not work as the list of supplier invoices are only changed once. It's the property Use in the class SupplierInvoice that the List is made up of that keeps changing

Comment: That makes little difference. Your solution is for you to call `this.RaisePropertyChanged("ApTotal");` whenever you recalculate the `ApTotal` property.